# HQL Path expected for join (when joining same table)

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, hql, inner-join

I am trying to get pairs of measurement for two different devices, joined on equal Timestamps. In SQL, this works as expected:

```
select
  leftItem.Timestamp, leftItem.Value, rightItem.Value
from
  DataTable leftItem
  inner join DataTable rightItem
  on leftItem.Timestamp = rightItem.Timestamp
where
  leftItem.Device = 1 and rightItem.Device = 2
```

But if I try to convert it to HQL:

```
select
  left, right 
from
  DataTable as left 
  inner join DataTable as right
  on left.Timestamp = right.Timestamp
where
  left.Device = 1 and right.Device = 2
```

I get a `NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.SemanticException:`

```
Path expected for join!
```

How do I specify a "path" to the same table?

Comment: what did you try in HQL when you got this error?

Comment: @Stefan: this same query, actually. (ok, i'll edit it to clarify)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In HQL, joins can only be done on associations between entities. If you want a join on something else, the only possibility is to make the join in the where clause:

```
select left, right 
from
  DataTable as left, DataTable as right
where
  left.Timestamp = right.Timestamp
  and left.Device = 1 
  and right.Device = 2
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a difference in how this will be evaluated on the server (performance wise)? Or difference in results? Because I could also resort to plain SQL, after all.

Comment: Turn on SQL logging to see the generated SQL, and compare the two execution plans. This is database-dependent.